# Can the contents of a string variable be sorted without using an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In c++ how can I read a list of names inside of a string variable and sort them in alphabetical order without using an array ? Is it possible?

I haven't tried anything yet. I just want to know how it can be done.

Comment: Are you talking about having a string like "Bob Alice John" and having the output be "Alice Bob John", but without using another data structure (like an array) to complete the sort?

Comment: You can put the individual names in plenty of different containers that aren't arrays.  Can you use a `std::vector`?  Can you use a `std::list`?  If you can't use anything that is "array-like", that also rules out using a string variable.

Comment: No vectors or lists.

Comment: Yes Nick. That's the kind of sorting I'm talking about

Comment: I can't use anything but a string. Is it possible?

Comment: What you are asking for is *doable*, but not necessarily *trivial* to do just inside the string directly. If you know the starting and ending positions of 2 entries within the string, you can easily compare them using `std::string::compare()` or equivalent. It is moving them around within the string that becomes tricky but not impossible, since you will have swap and rearrange not only their characters but possibly also characters in between them.

Answer (score 2):

of course you can. You can iterate over them after splitting the string on space repeatedly. Then write the next one to a new string buffer.

Use `std::string token = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));` to get the first name, repeat with a new start point to determine which one is the first, then use string::erase to remove it and write it to the end of the string or just write it to a new one.

Making it efficient is another matter, but the task itself is easy.

Comment: @Jojo Here's an [example implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/sYsM3nc6P)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - he has to do it without using an array.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on bubble sort with O(1) space complexity. All operations are in-place.

[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6f0389d028f1eb4)

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Count number of words in a string
// separated by whitespaces
unsigned count_words(const std::string& words) {
  bool found_space = true;
  unsigned nwords = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    if (std::isspace(words[i])) {
      found_space = true;
    } else if (found_space) {
      nwords++;
      found_space = false;
    }
  }

  return nwords;
}

// Use lexicographical order
// return lhs <= rhs
// lhs = words[lhs_i..lhs_j]
// rhs = words[rhs_i..rhs_j]
bool lhs_le_rhs(const std::string& words, unsigned lhs_i, unsigned lhs_j,
                unsigned rhs_i, unsigned rhs_j) {
  unsigned p = lhs_i, q = rhs_i;
  for (; p <= lhs_j && q <= rhs_j; p++, q++) {
    if (words[p] < words[q]) {
      return true;
    }
    if (words[p] > words[q]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (p <= lhs_j && q > rhs_j) return false;
  if (q <= rhs_j && p > lhs_j) return true;

  // lhs == rhs
  return true;
}

// Swap two consecutive words in-place
void swap_consecutive_words(std::string& words, unsigned lhs_i, unsigned lhs_j,
                            unsigned rhs_i, unsigned rhs_j) {
  auto reverse_in_place = [&](unsigned start, unsigned end) {
    assert(start <= end);
    for (unsigned i = start, j = end; i < j; i++, j--) {
      std::swap(words[i], words[j]);
    }
  };

  // reverse words[lhs_i...lhs_j]
  reverse_in_place(lhs_i, lhs_j);

  // reverse words[rhs_i...rhs_j]
  reverse_in_place(rhs_i, rhs_j);

  // reverse words[lhs_i...rhs_j]
  reverse_in_place(lhs_i, rhs_j);
}

// Find the starting index of the next word, starting from start_idx
// if not found, return the length of `words`
unsigned find_next_word_start_idx(const std::string& words,
                                  unsigned start_idx) {
  for (unsigned i = start_idx; i < words.size(); i++) {
    if (!std::isspace(words[i])) return i;
  }
  return words.size();
}

// Given the starting index of a word, find its
// ending index
unsigned find_next_word_end_idx(const std::string& words, unsigned start_idx) {
  for (unsigned i = start_idx + 1; i < words.size(); i++) {
    if (std::isspace(words[i])) return i - 1;
  }
  return words.size() - 1;
}

// Bubble sort words in a string
void word_bubble_sort(std::string& words) {
  bool swapped = false;

  // Get number of words
  auto nwords = count_words(words);
  if (nwords <= 1) return;

  auto first_word_start_idx = find_next_word_start_idx(words, 0);

  for (int i = nwords - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int word_count = 0;
    auto lhs_start_idx = first_word_start_idx;
    auto lhs_end_idx = find_next_word_end_idx(words, lhs_start_idx);

    while (word_count < i) {
      auto rhs_start_idx = find_next_word_start_idx(words, lhs_end_idx + 1);
      if (rhs_start_idx == words.size()) break;
      auto rhs_end_idx = find_next_word_end_idx(words, rhs_start_idx);

      // if words[lhs_start_idx..lhs_end_idx] >
      // words[rhs_start_idx..rhs_end_idx],
      // swap these two words in-place
      if (!lhs_le_rhs(words, lhs_start_idx, lhs_end_idx, rhs_start_idx,
                      rhs_end_idx)) {
        swap_consecutive_words(words, lhs_start_idx, lhs_end_idx, rhs_start_idx,
                               rhs_end_idx);
        swapped = true;

        // Move to next word after swapping
        lhs_start_idx += rhs_end_idx - lhs_end_idx;
        lhs_end_idx = rhs_end_idx;
      } else {
        // Move to next word
        lhs_start_idx = rhs_start_idx;
        lhs_end_idx = rhs_end_idx;
      }

      word_count++;
    }

    // Early return if no swap is performed
    if (!swapped) return;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string words = " Zak Bob  William Johnson  Alice John ";
  std::cout << "       words = " << std::quoted(words) << std::endl;
  word_bubble_sort(words);
  std::cout << "sorted words = " << std::quoted(words) << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```bash
       words = " Zak Bob  William Johnson  Alice John "
sorted words = " Alice Bob  John Johnson  William Zak "
```

A few notes:

1. Lexicographical order is used to compare two words.
2. Words are separated by one or more whitespaces.
3. All whitespaces (leading, middle, trailing) are preserved.